# How to use jquery when function with Get Request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that requesting and getting data from server

```
function TaskFinishedRequestAccepted(requestId, empTaskAssignCompletionId, selectedFinishedTaskMiainId, selectedFinishedTaskStautsDetail, requestByEmpId){
    var go_path = "ESP.php?action=tfrq&vars=5&var1=" + requestId +
        "&var2=" + empTaskAssignCompletionId + "&var3=" + selectedFinishedTaskMiainId + "&var4=" + selectedFinishedTaskStautsDetail + "&var5=" + requestByEmpId;
    $jq.get(go_path,{},function(data) {

    });

}
```

And I am calling this function in order to get it's **return data** in this way,
code given below (which is wrong, seeking help for it)

```
$.when(TaskFinishedRequestAccepted(2,3,4,5,33)).done(function(return){
console.log(return);
});
```

But I don't know how to return actually? So that I can get its response in done function.

Comment: Don't use `return` as the name of your argument... check `function(return)`

Comment: sorry return wasn't parameter, i have removed that

Comment: Update the code to be the relevant to what you have now and ask the question

Comment: @Dekel above is actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply return the deferred object from your function. There's no need to use `when`. Also, jQuery offers a much more convenient way to construct URL query parameters...

```
return $jq.get('ESP.php', {
  action: 'tfrq',
  vars: 5,
  var1: requestId,
  var2: empTaskAssignCompletionId,
  var3: selectedFinishedTaskMiainId,
  var4: selectedFinishedTaskStautsDetail,
  var5: requestByEmpId
})
```

and

```
TaskFinishedRequestAccepted(2,3,4,5,33).done(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Yes its working, i were not familiar with this way. Thanks